# Incorrect work of the desktop and adaptive menu when hovering and clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make an adaptive menu. The problem now is that in the desktop version, when you click on a menu item and its sub-items, it closes, and should only work while I am hovering over it. And in the mobile version with an adaptive less than 520px, it also closes when you click on a sub-menu item, and this is bad.

I need hover to work only in desktop version. Also I need a menu to not get closed after the click on the sub-items. 
That also goes for mobile version.

```js
$('.drop__down-menu').on('click', function(){
  $(this).children('.drop__down-list').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.header__menu-inner {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 80px;
}
 .menu__header {
  max-width: 750px;
}
 .menu__header li {
  display: inline-block;
}
 .menu__header li + li {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
 .menu__header a {
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 42px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #333;
}
 .menu__header a:hover {
  color: blue;
}
 .drop__down-menu {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
 .drop__down-list {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 61px;
  left: 0;
  width: 270px;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  border-top: 1px solid blue;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 40px 0px rgba(82, 85, 90, 0.2);
  border-top: 1px solid blue;
  z-index: 2;
}
 .drop__down-list li {
  width: 100%;
}
 .drop__down-list li + li {
  margin-left: 0;
}
 .drop__down-list li a {
  display: block;
  line-height: 44px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
 .drop__down-list li a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: blue;
}
 .drop__down-menu:hover .drop__down-list {
  display: block;
}
 @media (max-width: 520px) {
  .header__user-nav + .header__user-nav {
   margin-left: 5px;
 }
  .menu__header {
   margin-left: auto;
 }
  .menu__header a {
   line-height: 30px;
 }
  .menu__header-btn {
   width: 30px;
 }
  .menu__header-btn span {
   height: 4px;
 }
  .menu__header-btn span + span {
   margin-top: 3px;
 }
  .menu__header-list {
   left: 0;
   top: 56px;
 }
  .menu__header-list li {
   display: block;
   border-bottom: 1px solid #0c0c0c;
 }
  .menu__header-list li a {
   display: block;
 }
  .menu__header li + li {
   margin-left: 0;
 }
  .drop__down-list {
   width: 100%;
 }
  .header__menu-inner {
   min-height: 55px;
 }
  .drop__down-list {
   padding: 0 12px;
   top: 40px;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="wrap">  
  <div class="content">
   <header class="header">
    <div class="header__menu-inner">                                              
            <nav class="menu__header">
                <div class="menu__header-btn">
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                </div>
                <ul class="menu__header-list">
                    <li class="drop__down-menu">
                        <a href="#" class="drop__down-link">Home</a>
                        <ul class="drop__down-list">
                            <li><a href="#">Home One Multi User</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Home Two Single User</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Home Three Product</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="drop__down-menu">
                        <a href="#" class="drop__down-link">All products</a>
                        <ul class="drop__down-list">
                            <li><a href="#">Recent Items</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Popular Items</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Featured Items</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="drop__down-menu">
                        <a href="#" class="drop__down-link">Wordpress</a>
                        <ul class="drop__down-list">
                            <li><a href="#">Popular Items</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Admin Templates</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Blog / Magazine / News</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Festures</a></li>
                    <li class="drop__down-menu link__mega-menu">
                        <a class="drop__down-link" href="#">Pages</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
   </header>
  </div>
 </div> 
    <!--Plugin JavaScript file-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want the final result to be. Please clarify

Comment: @Edit I need hover to work only in desktop version. Also I need a menu to not get closed after the click on the sub-items. 
That also goes for mobile version.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this answer helps you!

```
@media (min-width: 520px){
  .drop__down-menu:hover .drop__down-list {
    display: block;
}
```

I think you should adapt CSS style for mobile first.
then add @media (min-width: x) for large devices not inversely

Comment: It works but is wrong. In the desktop version, the menu responds to a click, and should only respond to a hover. And in the mobile version, if you click on a sub-item, then the menu is hidden.

Comment: I've modified the answer. check it